# Open mesh of array indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Given a matrix `a` where `a.shape == (M, N, O)`, does there exist a better way to generate:

```
indices = (
    np.arange(M).reshape(M, 1, 1),
    np.arange(N).reshape(1, N, 1),
    np.arange(O).reshape(1, 1, O)
)
```

And also works for higher-dimensions of array?

I can get close with `np.indices`, but this returns a closed mesh (all entries are of shape `M,N,O`), not an open mesh.

Answer (score 3):

You can possibly do this with [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html):

```
np.ix_(np.arange(M), np.arange(N), np.arange(O))
```

From the documentation:

> Construct an open mesh from multiple sequences.
>
> This function takes N 1-D sequences and returns N outputs with N dimensions each, such that the shape is 1 in all but one dimension and the dimension with the non-unit shape value cycles through all N dimensions.

This produces the same result as `indices` here (`M, N, O = 2, 3, 4`):

```
(array([[[0]],
 
        [[1]]]), 

 array([[[0],
         [1],
         [2]]]), 

 array([[[0, 1, 2, 3]]]))
```

Comment: So for the general case, `np.ix_(*(np.arange(s) for s in A.shape))`? Bit of a mouthful

Comment: Perhaps, but it's a *little* more concise. I'll see if I can think of anything better (and also hope someone else contributes a nicer solution) in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

[`np.ogrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html) is probably the most concise method if `M`, `N` and `O` are specified separately:

```
M, N, O = 2, 3, 4

indices = np.ogrid[:M, :N, :O]

print(indices)
# [array([[[0]],

#        [[1]]]), array([[[0],
#         [1],
#         [2]]]), array([[[0, 1, 2, 3]]])]
```

If the input is just the array itself, the most concise way I can think of is:

```
np.ix_(*(np.r_[:s] for s in A.shape))
```

Comment: Can I do this in one line given `a`?

Comment: Yep, with `np.ogrid[[np.s_[:s] for s in A.shape]]`

Comment: `np.ogrid` (and `ix_`) does the same thing you did, but with a lot more code.  It's just packaged as a class instance.